# Does the AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath function really need an iOS.ADBannerView.Type?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The documentation says it does but I don't see how that makes any sense. Why would a generic asset load need a banner ad? Really seems like an error and obviously makes understanding how to implement this difficult...

Here's the page in question: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through experimentation (and IntelliSense) I confirmed that this is indeed an error. It wants a System.Type. Here's my implementation in C# in case it helps anyone:

```
    public static Texture btnFireAuto;
```

...

```
    string[] searchInFolders = new string[] { "Assets/_TEXTURES" };
    var guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("agFireAuto", searchInFolders);

    if (guids.Length == 0) {
        Debug.Log("Can't find agFireAuto icon.");
    } else {
        foreach (var guid in guids) {
            string sGuid = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guid);
            btnFireAuto = (Texture)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(sGuid, typeof(Texture));
        }
    }
```

Note that this was for editor hacking (the enclosing class derived from EditorWindow). Assets loaded in-game must be under Assets/Resources/ .

Comment: This error with Unity's documentation generation happens a lot; basically, everywhere there should be a `Type` it shows `iOS.ADBannerView.Type` instead.